# Solving Errors Produced By Sailfish Harbour tool

Tags: qt, sailfish-os

I am completely new to sailfish(and linux) app development.
When i compiled and tested my sample sailfish app in Harbour Tool(inside sailfishos IDE) it produced following errors.
  Since i dont know what causes this error, unable to resolve it.
Here are the errors.

## Libraries

ERROR [/usr/bin/harbour-myapp] ELF file with wrong arch: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=89d564b54f9c18751d6a15e9747fad188871327b, stripped
FAILED

## Symbols

ERROR [/usr/bin/harbour-myapp] Binary does not link to __libc_start_main@GLIBC_2.4.
FAILED

Workig Environment = Windows8 with sailfishos IDE v5.2.1
I dint added any libraries or anything.Its Just a Simple Test App.
Any Solution will be really helpfull.
thanks in advance & sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These errors occure if you try to validate a i486 package with the Harbour tool which only validates armv7hl packages.

Go to the kit selection and select "MerSDK-SailfishOS-armv7hl" -> Release -> "Deploy by building an RPM Package".

If you make a deployment the QT-Creator will create an RPM for the correct architecture and the validation should look fine, the errors are gone.